# Glassfish, EC2, Swing Application not connecting to @remote interface

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, glassfish, ejb-3.0, ear

I have Glassfish with an EAR deployed that includes a swing application that I run through Java Web Start which connects to my EJB through the @remote interface.

We have a server set up with a static IP and all I need to do is set /etc/hostname to my hostname (x.x.com) and in my /etc/hosts I have:

127.0.0.1 localhost
x.x.x.x   x.x.com

Pretty simple. The application runs fine.

However, we want to migrate to EC2. I have a server up with Glassfish and everything is great. I have an Elastic IP pointed to it and my domain name pointed to that. All good.

The program downloads and updates fine also through Java Web Start.

The problem comes when trying to connect from my swing app to the server. It connects through CORBA, which I don't know much about.

I can't set the /etc/hosts file because the Elastic IP isn't the IP Address. Amazon assigns local addresses to the servers. I can't set /etc/hosts to one of those because if they were restarted it would change. And I don't want to edit it every time.

Does anyone know how to bypass this or fix it so Glassfish doesn't need it? It is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to add an entry to your hosts file for your eIP - have you tried that?

EC2 instances all have a public IP and a private 10.X.X.X address. The eIP replaces the public IP address and is fixed (until you disassociate it).

The alternative with AWS, which will allow you to have a fixed private IP too, is to deploy to a VPC. [Amazon have some very good documentation on VPCs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario1.html).

What you're getting, in a nutshell, is comparable to a local network, so you can just pick your CIDR block and create subnets, for example 10.0.1.0/24. Now, when you launch an EC2 instance, you can launch into that VPC subnet and **choose the private IP**. Along with your eIP, you now have both IP addresses (public and private) set permanently, unless you decide to change them yourself (for whatever reason).

You can even add secondary IP addresses if you want.